# Prove $\forall z\left(\left(\exists xA\rightarrow A_{x}[z]\right)\rightarrow B\right)\vDash B$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, satisfiability

I'm doing some self-exercises on mathematical logic by myself and have come across this question which I can't seem to prove:

> Let $A$ be a formula with a single free variable $x$. Let $B$ be a
>   formula also, and $z$ be a variable that does not appear in $A$ or in
>   $B$
>
> Prove:
>
> $\forall z\left(\left(\exists xA\rightarrow A_{x}[z]\right)\rightarrow B\right)\vDash B$

My train of thought was this:
The meaning of $A \vDash B$ is that a structure that satisfies A also satisfies B: $M \vDash A \Rightarrow M \vDash B$

With that in mind, I started trying to understand what the meaning of $ C = (\exists xA\rightarrow A_{x}[z])$ was, and came to the conclusion that if said formula C is always $True$ then I would get the following:

$(True) \rightarrow B = \urcorner(True) \vee B = (False) \vee B $

And in this situation, for a structure to satisfy C it has to satisfy B thus proving the claim.

The thing is that I don't know (or know how to prove) if C is always $True$. It seems logical in a way, since if I am replacing all free occurrences of $x$ by $z$ (which does not appear in A) then A itself doesn't really change and so C will be $True$ depending if the structure satisfies A or not.

Is my train of thought OK? or am I missing something?
Is there maybe another way of proving it?

Thank you to anyone who helps!

Comment: If you take $A$ to be $x = 0$ (in the language of natural number arithmetic), then $\exists xA$ is true but $A_x[z]$ is falsifiable, so your formula $C$ is not true in general. Are you have written the question down correctly? (This looks like an instance of the Drinker's paradox http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox if you move the brackets and quantifiers around.)

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, just checked and that is the way the question is written.

Comment: OK. The question is right (I misread it), but your approach isn't quite right (it doesn't make use of the fact that $z$ does not appear free in $B$. Using that, you can prove it by considering whether or not $\exists x A$ holds in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to work with Rob's comment above.

We have that :

> $\vDash (∃xβ → α) ↔ ∀x(β → α)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$.

Thus : $\forall z [(\exists x A(x) \rightarrow A(x/z)) \rightarrow B]$ is equivalent to : $\exists z (A(x) \rightarrow A(x/z)) \rightarrow B$.

We have also that :

> $\vDash (α → ∃xβ) ↔ ∃x(α → β)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$.

Thus : $\exists z (A(x) \rightarrow A(x/z))$ is equivalent to : $A(x) \rightarrow \exists z A(z)$.

In conclusion, our formula is equivalent to :

> $(A(x) \rightarrow \exists z A(z)) \rightarrow B$

and the antecedent is *valid*.

We can now use the heuristic considerations above to prove it "semantically".

Consider a structure $\mathcal M$ such that $\mathcal M \vDash \forall z [(\exists x A(x) \rightarrow A(x/z)) \rightarrow B]$.

We have two cases : if $\mathcal M \vDash B$ we are done.

Assume insted that we have : $\mathcal M \nvDash B$; but then we must have that $(\exists x A(x) \rightarrow A(x/z))[d]$ must be falsified for all $d \in |\mathcal M|$, and this is impossible.

---

We can prove with *Natural Deduction* that :

> > $\forall z [(∃xA(x) \rightarrow A(z)) \rightarrow B] \vdash B$.

*Proof* :

> 1) $\forall z [(∃xA(x) \rightarrow A(z)) \rightarrow B]$ --- premise

2) $(∃xA(x) \rightarrow A(z)) \rightarrow B$ --- from 1) by $\forall$-elimination

3) $\lnot A(z)$ --- assumed [a]

4) $\forall x \lnot A(x)$ --- from 3) by $\forall$-introduction

5) $\lnot \exists x A(x)$ --- from 4) with : $\forall x \lnot A(x) \rightarrow \lnot \exists x A(x)$ by $\rightarrow$-elimination

6) $\exists x A(x)$ --- assumed [b]

7) $\bot$ --- from 5) and 6) by $\rightarrow$-elimination

8) $A(z)$ --- from 3) and 7) by *Double Negation*, discharging [a]

9) $\exists x A(x) \rightarrow A(z)$ --- from 6) and 8) by $\rightarrow$-introduction, discharging [b]

> 10) $B$ --- from 2) and 9) by $\rightarrow$-elimination.

Comment: Your proof is syntactical while question was about semantic entailment. OP has not indicated that completeness holds for his system.